# SuExec is not giving permission to apache user

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, amazon-ec2

I am not much aware of SuExec .. As I see SuExec module is loaded in httpd.conf..

In my virtualhost tag i have given

SuexecUserGroup apache apache

But when i run the project it tells permission denied

Any idea..?

Thanks

Comment: Check your `ErrorLog` and the SuExec log file.

Answer (score 0):

SuExec doesn't make much sense if you are trying to run everything as the apache user.  The default config of apache will generally do this for you.

Check the error log.  There are probably incorrect permissions on the file, and it should be giving you an error.